# How to take screenshot of complete desktop Windows c#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, msdn

Below code is taking screenshot of desktop window only. My expectation is to take screenshot with taskbar and everything visible to the user.

Any help would be appreciated

'''
{

```
       //Creating a new Bitmap object

      Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 768, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

   
     //Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(int width, int height, PixelFormat);

     //Creating a Rectangle object which will  

     //capture our Current Screen

     Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;



     //Creating a New Graphics Object

     Graphics captureGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(captureBitmap);



    //Copying Image from The Screen

    captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(captureRectangle.Left,captureRectangle.Top,0,0,captureRectangle.Size);



    //Saving the Image File (I am here Saving it in My E drive).

    captureBitmap.Save(@"E:\Capture.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);



    //Displaying the Successfull Result



    MessageBox.Show("Screen Captured");

}
```

'''

Comment: You have to change
Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(1024, 768, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
to
Bitmap captureBitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Your bitmap was to small

Comment: @Triims, I tried with  below code also.but still i am not getting task bar
var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                          Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                          PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Comment: Thats weird, I tested it and by changing that line it worked for me.
Is a file created at that location?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/17034

Comment: There's no question. Read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine for you, duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046083/save-print-screen-in-c-sharp)

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
```