# How to take screenshot of current screen and not only the visible desktop?

Tags: c#, screen, screenshot

I am trying to write a program that takes a screenshot every x seconds of the entire desktop.
However, using the solutions i have found online i am only getting a partial desktop capture, usually the top left quarter of the screen.

I have tried a couple of different options detailed in these threads however, they both have the same issue.

[How to take screenshot of complete desktop Windows c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551723/how-to-take-screenshot-of-complete-desktop-windows-c-sharp)

[Take screenshot of multiple desktops of all visible applications and forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847637/take-screenshot-of-multiple-desktops-of-all-visible-applications-and-forms)

How can i ensure regardless of screen resolution, that i capture the entire screen?

Comment: Please show your code snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046083/save-print-screen-in-c-sharp Answer there should be fine. You can take all the screens available and just take screenshot for all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture the Screen into a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362986/capture-the-screen-into-a-bitmap) and [Capture the screen shot using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049122/capture-the-screen-shot-using-net)

Comment: Have you tried SystemInformation.VirtualScreen?

Comment: Thanks Guys sorry for the confusing title, i was meaning entire screen not just the desktop. But the 2nd reply answered my question and is now working perfectly.